# Reflection on EmberJS objects? How to find a list of property keys without knowing the keys in advance

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to retrieve the set-at-creations properties of an EmberJS object if you don't know all your keys in advance?

Via the inspector I see all the object properties which appear to be stored in the meta-object's `values` hash, but I can't seem to find any methods to get it back.  For example `object.getProperties()` needs a key list, but I'm trying to create a generic object container that doesn't know what it will contain in advance, but is able to return information about itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I haven't used this in production code, so your mileage may vary, but reviewing the Ember source suggests two functions that might be useful to you, or at least worth reviewing the implementation:

`Ember.keys`: "Returns all of the keys defined on an object or hash. This is useful when inspecting objects for debugging.  On browsers that support it, this uses the native Object.keys implementation." [Object.keys documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

`Ember.inspect`: "Convenience method to inspect an object. This method will attempt to convert the object into a useful string description." [Source on Github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/utils.js#L412)

Comment: Ember.inspect doesn't, say, ignore keys beginning with an underscore `_`. It's rather simple compared to something like github.com/NV/jsDump

Comment: This now gives a deprecation notice `ember.debug.js:5549 DEPRECATION: Ember.keys is deprecated in favor of Object.keys [deprecation id: ember-metal.ember.keys]`

Answer (score 5):

I believe the simple answer is: you don't find a list of props. At least I haven't been able to.

However I noticed that ember props appear to be prefixed `__ember`, which made me solve it like this:

```
for (f in App.model) { 
    if (App.model.hasOwnProperty(f) && f.indexOf('__ember') < 0) { 
       console.log(f);
    }
 };
```

And it seems to work. But I don't know whether it's 100% certain to not get any bad props.

EDIT: Adam's gist is provided from comments. https://gist.github.com/1817543

```
var getOwnProperties = function(model){
  var props = {};
  for(var prop in model){
    if( model.hasOwnProperty(prop) 
        && prop.indexOf('__ember') < 0
        && prop.indexOf('_super') < 0
        && Ember.typeOf(model.get(prop)) !== 'function'
    ){
      props[prop] = model[prop];
    }
  }
  return props;
}
```

Comment: I added `(Ember.typeOf(App.model.p) !== "function")` to your if() statement, which suited my needs, but that seems to work well enough.  I'll wait a bit to see if someone provides a more "correct" version (since you are right in saying this seems a bit fragile) and I'll accept it if nothing better comes up.

Comment: There is an error in my comment above..  It should be `(Ember.typeOf(App.model.get(p)) !== "function")`

Comment: Turned Seb Barre's simple function into something on Ember.Object.prototype [here](http://jsfiddle.net/algesten/5Hj9E/)

Comment: Unfortunately, using hasOwnProperty to reject properties leaves us only with properties defined inside the create() method. This means that any default properties we declare in the model will not be returned. 

Removing that leaves us with extra properties such as 'isInstance' which we do not want.

Updated example can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adjohu/rZkQj/). I've changed it slightly to use getProperties to retrieve the properties.

For my purposes, isInstance isn't a problem so I will leave you to improve it further if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of these answers are reliable, unfortunately, because any keys paired with a `null` or `undefined` value will not be visible.

e.g.

```
MyClass = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    age: null,
    weight: null,
    height: null
});
test = MyClass.create({name: 'wmarbut'});
console.log( Ember.keys(test) );
```

Is only going to give you

```
["_super", "name"]
```

The solution that I came up with is:

```
/**
* Method to get keys out of an object into an array
* @param object obj_proto The dumb javascript object to extract keys from
* @return array an array of keys
*/
function key_array(obj_proto) {
    keys = [];
    for (var key in obj_proto) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
}


/*
* Put the structure of the object that you want into a dumb JavaScript object
* instead of directly into an Ember.Object
*/
MyClassPrototype = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    weight: null,
    height: null
}

/*
* Extend the Ember.Object using your dumb javascript object
*/
MyClass = Ember.Object.extend(MyClassPrototype);

/*
* Set a hidden field for the keys the object possesses
*/
MyClass.reopen({__keys: key_array(MyClassPrototype)});
```

Using this method, you can now access the `__keys` field and know which keys to iterate over. This does not, however, solve the problem of objects where the structure isn't known before hand.

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
Ember.keys(Ember.meta(App.YOUR_MODEL.proto()).descs)
```

Comment: .proto seems not a workging function anymore. Instead, you could use toJSON: `Ember.keys( modelObject.toJSON() );`

Answer (score 1):

None of those answers worked with me. I already had a solution for Ember Data, I was just after one for Ember.Object. I found the following to work just fine. (Remove `Ember.getProperties` if you only want the keys, not a hash with key/value.

```
getPojoProperties = function (pojo) {
    return Ember.getProperties(pojo, Object.keys(pojo));
},
getProxiedProperties = function (proxyObject) {
    // Three levels, first the content, then the prototype, then the properties of the instance itself
    var contentProperties = getPojoProperties(proxyObject.get('content')),
        prototypeProperties = Ember.getProperties(proxyObject, Object.keys(proxyObject.constructor.prototype)),
        objectProperties = getPojoProperties(proxyObject);
    return Ember.merge(Ember.merge(contentProperties, prototypeProperties), objectProperties);
},
getEmberObjectProperties = function (emberObject) {
    var prototypeProperties = Ember.getProperties(emberObject, Object.keys(emberObject.constructor.prototype)),
        objectProperties = getPojoProperties(emberObject);
    return Ember.merge(prototypeProperties, objectProperties);
},
getEmberDataProperties = function (emberDataObject) {
    var attributes = Ember.get(emberDataObject.constructor, 'attributes'),
        keys = Ember.get(attributes, 'keys.list');
    return Ember.getProperties(emberDataObject, keys);
},
getProperties = function (object) {
    if (object instanceof DS.Model) {
        return getEmberDataProperties(object);
    } else if (object instanceof Ember.ObjectProxy) {
        return getProxiedProperties(object);
    } else if (object instanceof Ember.Object) {
        return getEmberObjectProperties(object);
    } else {
        return getPojoProperties(object);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case `Ember.keys(someObject)` worked, without doing `someObject.toJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar, i.e. render a generic table of rows of model data to show columns for each attribute of a given model type, but let the model describe its own fields.

If you're using Ember Data, then this may help:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachAttribute

You can iterate the attributes of the model type and get meta data associated with each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (from an ArrayController):

```
  fields: function() {
    var doc = this.get('arrangedContent');

      var fields = [];
      var content = doc.content;
      content.forEach(function(attr, value) {
        var data = Ember.keys(attr._data);
        data.forEach(function(v) {
           if( typeof v === 'string' && $.inArray(v, fields) == -1) {
             fields.push(v);
           }
         });
      });
    return fields;
  }.property('arrangedContent')
```